# I deleted the WSUSService, how can I re-do this?

Tags: windows-server-2012, wsus

I acidentially typed in my cmd: sc delete WSUSService. And now my WSUS gives the error: `One or more Updates Service components could not be contacted. Check your server status and ensure that Windows Server Update Services is running. Non-running services: WSUSService`. I can still see all my updates and computers tho. How can I re-get the WSUSService?

EDIT: Another problem (or maybe the same): In my Server Manager @ Services it tells me the WSUSService is stopped. When I try to start it, it tells me: `Failed, one or more services cannot be started`

EDIT2: After trying to start WSUSService in the `services`. I got the error: `Error 2: the system cannot find the file specified`. My wsuscontent folder is in c:

Thanks in advance

Comment: Re-Install this role with Server Manager.

Comment: I tried but it didnt work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I honestly don't know if this will work but you are welcome to try it.

You can try to recreate the service with:

`sc create WSUSService binpath= "C:\Program Files\Update Services\Service\bin\WsusService.exe" start= auto`

I would make sure that Network Service is the logon account and set it to "restart on failure".

Comment: I did the `sc create WSUSService binpath= "C:\Program Files\Update Services\Service\bin\WsusService.exe" start= auto` and rebooted, but it didnt help. Where can I set my logon account to restart on failure? thanks for helping me out

Comment: On the "recovery" tab.  but make sure on the Log On tab you have changed it to "This Account" and used NETWORK SERVICE as the account name (no password). (To specify that the service uses the Network Service account, click This account , and then type NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService_ -- but again if this doesn't work I would look at contacting MS support if you want to retain your existing database/environment.

Comment: I cannot find the recovery tab, I am using Windows server 2012. Also I edited my question, to make the problem a bit more clear

Comment: I would then recommend backing up the database and content folders and then removing WSUS and reinstalling it.  But if you are paranoid I'd hit up MS support.

Comment: I tried to remove WSUS before, but i cannot find it in programs and features. anyways, thanks for helping me out

Answer (score 1):

I don´t know why you have execute `sc delete WSUSService` but anyway: Do you have checked the [sc command](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc990289.aspx)? `sc create ...`should solve your problem.
On the other side: You could repair WSUS like described on the [Technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg680316.aspx) (Long articel - I won´t copy and paste the whole article). And on the other side: Do you have tried to repair the software or reinstall?

Comment: I cannot find where to repair it, and i cant reinstall the service because it tells me its already installed